# How can I fix this pseudocode of Kruskal's algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

[image: Please click here to see the image]

So here, I am not sure what the while statement means. In the lecture note there is no definition for T or N or u or v. My guess is T is the minimum spinning tree, but is N the node? Why condition T to be smaller than N - 1?

And how about the case of a cycle? shouldn't we take that into consideration as well?

I understand how Kruskal works but i am just not sure what this pseudocode means.

Comment: If you understand how Kruskal works, you should be able to answer your questions yourself: just fix the algorithm so that it works as intended!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: We're not here to debug your teacher's code, or to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3):

$|T|$ is the number of edges in the forest $T$, eventually $T$ will become the required minimum spanning tree. |N| is the number of nodes of the graph (for which you are finding a MST). You start by an empty forest and at each step you add an edge that does not form a cycle. You stop once you have picked exactly $|N| - 1$ edges.

Answer (score 1):

**Goal: Compute MST of $G = (V, E)$.**

We have $ N = \lvert V \rvert $ in your pseudocode.

> In the lecture note there is no definition for T or N or u or v.

You can represent an edge $e \in E$ as a tuple $(u, v)$, where $u,v \in V$, meaning vertex $u$ has a link with vertex $v$.

Also, note that a Tree must have $N - 1$ edges, and no cycles. Kruskal deals with cycles by using a [Disjoint Set Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

**Step 1: Initialization and Sorting**

Initialize $ ~ T = \emptyset $.

Sort $~E~$ by edge weigth.

**Step 2: Building T**

If you naively take only the first $n$ edges there's a chance that $ ~ T ~$ will contain a cycle, and therefore be a MST. That's why there's an **if** statement checking whether two vertices are already in the same component. Looking at the example I've modified from Wikipedia:

[image: Iteration from state (A) to (B).]

If you greedily chose edge $(D,B)$ you'll end up with a cycle, however both $D$ and $E$ are in same component **(green)**, so the if condition fails.

Now the next iteration will check the next edge in sorted $E$, i.e. $(B, E)$.